# Export xlsx file on client meteor application

Tags: cordova, meteor, filesaver.js

I am sending bas64 encoded file from meteor server to my client. I am able to download that file using [pfafman:filesaver](https://github.com/pfafman/meteor-filesaver) after converting base64 encoded file to blob on web application but when i am trying same after building mobile application i am not able to download same way.

I want to download file on client side(both ios and android) using base64 encoded file sent from server. any suggestions?

this log what i am getting while i am trying to download it using filesaver.

```
chromium: [WARNING:render_frame_host_impl.cc(2728)] OnDidStopLoading was called twice.
```

Comment: As i am not able to find better option, i have adopted different approach where i am not saving file to client. i am sending file as attachment to user who is logged in. I know it's not solution but by the time i find proper solution it's really good work around.Hope it helps :)